# Stop button on Javascript countdown

Tags: javascript, html, button, countdowntimer

Having trouble stopping this countdown on button click, from what I've read `clearTimeout()` seems to be the best route. I'd like it to display the numbers stopped once clicked, so I can later on put it in a SQL table. This is meant to go negative, and once it does I have a  [skull and crossbones picture](http://cliparts.co/cliparts/8c6/8RG/8c68RGrzi.png) that should pop up every other second, overlapping the timer.

Why doesn't the countdown stop on button click?

**FIXED**

```js
    var seconds = 10;
    
function stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(countdownTimer)
}

function floor(x) {
    return x | 0;
}

function pad(n) {
    if (n < 0) {
      n = -n;
    }
    if (n < 10) {
        return '0' + n.toString();
    }
    return n.toString();
}

function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = pad(floor(seconds/60));
    if (seconds < 0) {
        minutes = '-' + minutes;
    }
    var remainingSeconds = pad(seconds % 60); 

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds > 8) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; }
        else if (seconds == 5) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";}
        else if (minutes == 0 & seconds == 0) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";}
    }
    else{
    seconds--;
   
        if (seconds == 0 || seconds == 2 || seconds == 4 || seconds == 6 || seconds == 8 ) {document.getElementById("Image1").style.visibility= "visible";}
        else {document.getElementById("Image1").style.visibility= "hidden";}
    }
}
```

```css
#bigfuckingspoon
{
 position:absolute;
 width:600px;
 height:500px;
    z-index:0;
}
#littlespoon
{
 z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<body onload = "getSeconds()">
<div id="littlespoon" align ="center">
<span id="countdown" style="color:black; font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold"></span>

<button onclick=" countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000)">Start</button>
<button onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>
</div>
    
    <div id="bigfuckingspoon">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl="\\scnas1\dev\vbdev\Time\skull.gif"
             />&nbsp;
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The countdownTimer var is not  reachable in the stop function. Remove the `var` keyword in the button onclick method.

```
<button onclick="countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000)">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000)">Start</button>
```

Using `var` scopes that variable to the current function. When used in the `onclick` I guess it's only available there. Remove `var` to make it global so then `clearTimeout(countdownTimer)` can see the `countdownTimer` variable